# Date comparison with todays date

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Please feel free to suggest changes to the title.

I have a hire date column and I want to assign specific tiers depending on employee work years with the following conditions:

```
    1-4 years = T1
    5-9 years = T2
    10-15 years = T3
    15+ years = T4
```

For example, if the hire date is 12/07/2002, the tier should be equal to T4.

I am comparing the dates to today's date.

```
     10/03/2016 = T1
     01/18/2010 = T2
     01/14/2006 = T3
     12/07/2002 = T4
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comparing with which date? Today?

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, today date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CASE statement to get your desired result set.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN hire_date < DATEADD(YY,-15,GETDATE()) THEN 'T4'
    WHEN hire_date < DATEADD(YY,-10,GETDATE()) THEN 'T3'
    WHEN hire_date < DATEADD(YY,-5,GETDATE()) THEN 'T2'
    ELSE 'T1'
END
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case when struct. ie:

```
select case 
when datediff(year, hireDate, getDate()) >= 15 then 'T4' 
when datediff(year, hireDate, getDate()) >= 10 then 'T3' 
when datediff(year, hireDate, getDate()) >= 5 then 'T2' 
else 'T1' 
end as egroup, id, hiredate 
from employees;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!